# Cannot open database connection

Tags: c#, ado.net

I created a C# console application, and need to access my database.

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=MyDB;";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

The `.Open()` gives an exception:

> "Cannot open database "MyDB" requested by the login. The login failed."

Could you please help me with this? Should I give some permission to my application? How can I do it on Windows 7?

Comment: Since you are using integrated security, does the Windwos id the program is running under have aouthority to access the MyDB databse ?

Comment: you do not have access to the server with your credentials.

Comment: I would like my program to be able to access the database from any computer. Is it possible to give authority to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows auth you shouldn't need a user name and password (your login to Windows is sufficient, assuming it has permissions on the database). Otherwise you'll need a username and password for the db.

Also, I'm not sure it matters, but always a good idea to run your application as admin when you have permissions issues.

Comment: How can I do that, if I am running it from Visual Studio?

Comment: @DavidShochet You have to open VS as admin. Those permissions are inherited by applications which are launched from it.

Comment: @DavidShochet That's because you have an authorizations problem. Running as admin will do nothing for you if you're still not authorized to access the database. Are you using MS SQL Server? If so open it up and check the authorization type. If your Windows credentials have access to the db, then you have another problem (like it's not finding the db). If it's not you need that user name and password added to your connection string.

Comment: @ evanmcdonnal If I can access the database through Management Studio, I probably have the access, right? I tried using userid and password, but it didn't help...

Comment: @DavidShochet Good to hear. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 3):

You should try specifying the user and the password in the connection string.

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=MyDB;user=you;password=password;";
```

Comment: You should decide to use **either** `Integrated Security=True;` or `User=you;password=...` - both at the same time doesn't make any sense!

Comment: @marc_s Marc is right. I missed that while copying the line from the op's post.